# How to create a column that calculates frequency of an ID in dataframe column?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have a column filled with user IDs as strings. I am trying to create a new column that counts how many other examples have the same user ID.

For example, a count of 10 for userId 1 indicates there are 10 other occurrences of this user elsewhere in the UserId column.

The number of rows in the new column should be equal to the number of rows in the dataframe.

```
>>> df = sc.parallelize([('6',10),('9',44),('6',30),('12',100),('9',99)]).toDF(['user','somecol'])
>>> df.show()
+----+-------+
|user|somecol|
+----+-------+
|   6|     10|
|   9|     44|
|   6|     30|
|  12|    100|
|   9|     99|
+----+-------+
```

would look like this:

```
+----+-------+
|user| count |
+----+-------+
|   6|      2|
|   9|      2|
|   6|      2|
|  12|      1|
|   9|      2|
+----+-------+
```

The idea is that the number of time a user occurs in the dataframe will be a useful input to a classifier.

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

# aggregate data
new_df = df.groupby('user').agg(F.count("somecol").alias("count"))

# add back to df
df = df.join(new_df, 'user').select('user','count')
df.show()

+----+-----+
|user|count|
+----+-----+
|   6|    2|
|   6|    2|
|   9|    2|
|   9|    2|
|  12|    1|
+----+-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing is to use a [`pyspark.sql.Window`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Window) and `select`:

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql import Window

w = Window.partitionBy('user')

df = df.select('user', f.count('somecol').over(w).alias('count'))
df.show()
#+-----+-------+
#|user| count |
#+----+-------+
#|   6|      2|
#|   9|      2|
#|   6|      2|
#|  12|      1|
#|   9|      2|
#+----+-------+
```

We define the Window `w` to partition by (group by) the `user` column. Then we calculate the count over this window.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `groupBy`

```
>>> df = sc.parallelize([('6',10),('9',44),('6',30),('12',100),('9',99)]).toDF(['user','somecol'])
>>> df.show()
+----+-------+
|user|somecol|
+----+-------+
|   6|     10|
|   9|     44|
|   6|     30|
|  12|    100|
|   9|     99|
+----+-------+

>>> df.groupBy('user').agg(count(col('somecol')).alias('total')).show()
+----+-----+                                                                    
|user|total|
+----+-----+
|   6|    2|
|   9|    2|
|  12|    1|
+----+-----+
```

Comment: That is close to what I'm trying to do, except I would like to keep the same number of rows.

The count will be used as an input feature.

Comment: I have edited the original question in the context of your input.